# protobuf repeatedly writes out a non-repeated field while serializing

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

i have a weird problem.

I added one field to my protobuf like this:

```
{
    optional uint32 avg_body_length = 90;
    optional uint32 pub_body_length = 95; //new field
}
```

My program(a service running continuously) updates pub_body_length and then writes it to some storage periodically.

After several hours, i found the size of the serialized protobuf grew rapidly.

By analyzing the serialized protobuf manually, it turns out field pub_body_length appears thousands of time with the same value.

I use c++ and the version of protoc is 2.4.1

Anyone has any clue?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Maybe you are appending to the storage instead of overwriting old data?